# why I receive 'Duplicate entry' error in django testing?

Tags: mysql, django, unit-testing, django-testing

I had some unit tests in Django that worked fine. I added some lines to send queries to MySQL. After that every unit test that includes authentication is raising exceptions, even I remove those lines. what is the problem?

### Django error report:

> _mysql.connection.query(self, query)
> django.db.utils.IntegrityError: (1062, "Duplicate entry 'myuser' for key 'auth_user.username'")

### My Tests:

```
class AnnotationPage(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.factory = RequestFactory()
        self.user = User.objects.create_user(
            username='myuser', password='12345678')


    def test_labeling(self):
        ajaxData = {'testing': 'True',
                    'direction': 'forward'}
        request = self.factory.post('/annotation', ajaxData)
        request.user = self.user
        response = AnnotationView(request)
        assert response.content == b'{"image": "image.png", "id": 1}'
```

### My Tests with queries:

```
class AnnotationPage(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.factory = RequestFactory()
        self.user = User.objects.create_user(
            username='myuser', password='12345678')
        self.cursor = connection.cursor()
        query = "TRUNCATE TABLE homepage_imagelabel"
        self.cursor.execute(query)


    def test_labeling(self):
        self.cursor = connection.cursor()
        query = "INSERT INTO homepage_imagelabel (ImageFile) VALUES ('image.png')"
        self.cursor.execute(query)
        ajaxData = {'testing': 'True',
                    'direction': 'forward'}
        request = self.factory.post('/annotation', ajaxData)
        request.user = self.user
        response = AnnotationView(request)
        assert response.content == b'{"image": "image.png", "id": 1}'
```

Comment: Do you have custom user model? usually this error means you try to create second Model instance with some field value where `unique=True`

Comment: Yes, I use a model in this page to which I was **sending queries**, but non of them had `unique=True`. By the way, the `username` must be unique, as the error says.

Comment: I fixed the issue by **reseting** the test database. now it works fine. yet I do not know the cause of the problem.